# Object doesn't align in SwiftUI sheet

Tags: swift, alignment, swiftui, swift-playground

I am using a sheet in Swift Playground and I want to align the plus sign to the top left of the screen, but when I try and run the code below, the plus doesn't get aligned it just remains in the centre of the sheet. Is there a way to fix this?

**Disclaimer:** I am using SwiftUI and Swift Playground

```
struct SecondView : View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var string: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI generally the bounds of the resulting parent view are dictated by the views inside it. In this case your overall view is bound by the Button (in the VStack), so aligning it any which way doesn't move it much (or at all) in it's tight confines. You'll see what I mean if you draw a border/background around the outermost View.

One solution is to use `Spacer()` to flexibly expand the inner view to take up the extra available space.

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
     HStack { 
       Button(...) // probably want to add some padding
       Spacer()
     }
     Spacer()
  }
}
```

or in the case of a dismiss button, look at adding it as an Overlay.

With Text below:

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
     VStack(spacing: 10) {
       HStack { 
         Button(...) // probably want to add some padding 
         Spacer()
       }
       Text(...)
     }
     Spacer()
  }
}
```

Comment: That moves the button to the top right which is great but when I add a Text under the 2nd spacer the text moves to the very bottom of the screen. How do I fix this? I added some padding to the bottom of the text to move it up but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: If you want the text closer to just below the button, then put it before the VStack spacer (which will fill all remaining space). You can also nest the HStack and Text in their own separate VStack where you can set the spacing (see the edit to the answer).  
There are other ways to do this overall, 1. overlaying the dismiss button,  2. get the bounds of the screen and use offsets; or 3. look into alignment guides. But this is probably the most straight-forward.